# Establishing B2B connection in NodeJS using EbXML and CPA file

Tags: node.js, b2b, ebxml

We need to establish a connection to B2B server using CPA programmatically.  We are having CPA file, payload((EbXML)) & end point in our hands.  We need to know how to request to B2B server by using CPA file?

We tried to request the endpoint in axios by passing the xml(EbXML) payload but don't know where to configure the CPA file like whether we have to send the CPA file in the request itself or we have to place the CPA file in the server like SSL?

As per the analysis currently B2B connections are made by tool like Oracle B2B and IBM sterling.  Our goal is to connect the B2B server without tools i.e via code

If anyone had experienced or any idea please let me know.